# C++ executable only starts from Visual Studio

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, exe

I have a program written in C++ which is compiled with Visual Studio 2013. It also uses Qt5. I can start the program from Visual Studio (debug/release), but if I try to start the .exe file outside of VS nothing happens. My assumption was that it's missing DLL files. According to "dumpbin /dependents" I need these DLLs:

> File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE
>
> Image has the following dependencies:
>
> ```
> Qt5OpenGL.dll
> Qt5Gui.dll
> Qt5Widgets.dll
> Qt5Core.dll
> MSVCP120.dll
> MSVCR120.dll
> KERNEL32.dll
> SHELL32.dll
> ```

I have those lying in the same directory as the .exe file. I copied msvcp120.dll and msvcr120.dll from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC120.CRT" and the Qt5 DLLs from "C:\Qt\5.4\msvc2013\bin".

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to C++, so I'm probably missing some knowledge here.

Comment: Two hints: Firstly, use "dependencywalker" on the executable. Secondly, open a commandline, CD to that directory and run it from there. That should at least give you some error messages, unless the program starts and immediately terminates, which is also a possibility.

Comment: is it running if you go into the task manager and look at processes?

Comment: It's not in the task manager. And running it from the command line in the folder of the .exe has no effect, it immediately goes back to the command line.

Comment: @Torben do you have any "Debugging" arguments in Visual Studio? Right click the project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging and check "Command Arguments"

Comment: No, the arguments are empty. "Dependency Walker" shows the same DLLs. It shows some errors, though because Qt5Widgets.dll seems to be dependent on some DLLs I don't even have on my system. But it works in VS2013...

Comment: Are you referencing any files, e.g., shader files (since you are using opengl), with hardcoded path from your application? Maybe the current working directory of the application is different when started via VS2013 and started as *.EXE.

Comment: I'm only referencing some .xml files, but I tried using the full path instead of a relative path for testing purposes and it worked in Visual Studio, but outside of Visual Studio the .exe still didn't want to start my program.

Comment: I just noticed that in VS the debugging "Environment" is set to "PATH=$(QTDIR)\bin;$(PATH)". When I start my program from the command line, change my working directory to my Qt5 bin path and start my .exe from there my program starts! I could probably add Qt to the Windows PATH, but then it still wouldn't work if the PATH is not properly set.

Answer (score 0):

My .exe was missing 3 DLLs: icudt53.dll, icuin53.dll, icuuc53.dll. "Dependency Walker" was actually showing them as missing, but I misinterpreted what it meant and thought they aren't on my system at all. But they can be found in $(QTDIR)\bin and my VS project added that path to the PATH variable, so in VS the DLLs weren't missing.

EDIT: It's actually way easier just to do this from the command line:

```
windeployqt C:\Path\To\My.exe
```

It will copy all needed DLLs into the .exe folder. It's even more DLLs than I thought. For example "qwindows.dll" is needed if you want to deploy the program on a machine without Qt.